# Parse a string with key-value pairs where there is no char between key and value c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split, key-value

I am trying to parse through a file line by line, each time setting variables equal to a value from the line.

Example lines would be:

```
G1 Z0.500 F7800.000
G1 X-0.336 Y13.564 F7800.000
G1 X3.205 Y13.493 E3.63071 F1800.000
```

I would have variables like:

```
double x;
double y;
double z;
```

Say I parse the first line, my output should be:

```
x = 100000;
y = 100000;
z = 0.5;
```

If I parsed the second line, my output should be:

```
x = -0.336;
y = 13.564;
z = 100000;
```

The third line is just another line that could come up, but all are fairly similar. If the key doesn't appear in the string, the values are set to 100,000.

I attempted to use code like this:

```
char[] delimiters = { 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
string[] words = line.Split(delimiters);
```

but that returned for the first line:

```
z = 0.500 F7800.000
```

What would be the best way to go about parsing each line for these key value pairs?

Comment: split on the space character and look for the leading characters that match your expected x,y,z chars, then convert the rest of the input to a double

Comment: @Amy Yeah, I tried using a character array of delimiters X Y and Z however it would of course return the entire string after a delimiter.

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question.

Comment: @RufusL I don't necessarily mean null for this. Rather it needs to be set to some arbitrary number that I haven't decided.

Comment: @RufusL - an `int` can't be `0.5` either.

Comment: @RufusL the int bit was a hasty mistake... however it really doesn't matter what the other values are set to. so 100,000 will work. My code elsewhere will check if it equals 100,000 it will be ignored.

Comment: I wouldn't use x,y,z as delimiters. Spaces are the delimiters. Then check the character that each segment starts with.

Comment: @mikez I see what you're saying... I think that will spark a solution here in a few minutes of coding... brb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started...

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    string[] items = line.Split(' ');
                    decimal? x, y, z = null;
                    for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (items[i].ToLower().StartsWith("x"))
                        {
                            x = decimal.Parse(items[i].Substring(1));
                            Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}");
                        }
                        else if (items[i].ToLower().StartsWith("y"))
                        {
                            y = decimal.Parse(items[i].Substring(1));
                            Console.WriteLine($"y = {y}");
                        }
                        else if (items[i].ToLower().StartsWith("z"))
                        {
                            z = decimal.Parse(str);
                            Console.WriteLine($"y = {z}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much the way I headed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a simple class that represents the data you care about, which appear to be `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. Then you can create a `static` method that knows how to create an instance of the class from a string.

For example:

```
public class XYZData
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public static XYZData Parse(string input)
    {
        var xyzData = new XYZData { X = 100000, Y = 100000, Z = 100000 };

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return xyzData;

        var parts = input.Split();

        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            double result;

            if (part.Length < 2 || 
                !double.TryParse(part.Substring(1), out result)) 
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (part.StartsWith("X", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                xyzData.X = result;
                continue;
            }
            if (part.StartsWith("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                xyzData.Y = result;
                continue;
            }
            if (part.StartsWith("Z", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                xyzData.Z = result;
                continue;
            }
        }

        return xyzData;
    }
}
```

Then you can populate a list of these things when reading your file:

```
var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";

var data = new List<XYZData>();

foreach (var fileLine in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    data.Add(XYZData.Parse(fileLine));
}
```